# Is "Many thanks" a proper usage?

Tags: grammaticality, email, valediction

I saw emails from English people with *Many Thanks* as a signing off phrase. Is that proper usage? Or is it a phrase created by continental English speakers due to the influence of their native language? (*Vielen Dank* in German and *muchas gracias* in Spanish translate to "many thanks".)

I have seen several other cases where one constructs imprecise sentences due to the influence of native language. This is evident especially in India.

Comment: Note that *Dank* in German is a [singulare tantum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurale_tantum#Related_terms); a more accurate literal translation would be "much gratitude".

Comment: There is some difference between British and American usage. See [here](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.co.uk/2017/07/thank-you-veryso-much.html)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Yes, *many thanks* is perfectly proper, grammatical, standard English. It is appropriate to use wherever "thanks" (as opposed to "thank you") would be acceptable.

Answer (score 16):

As Martha says, *many thanks* is perfectly idiomatic.  However, it is indeed an oddly isolated idiom: most other constructions which try to treat *thanks* as a plural noun are ungrammatical (eg **lots of thanks*), and there’s certainly no such thing as **a thank*.

In the sense of “feelings of gratitude” it can be used either as a mass noun (*thanks is due to God for this harvest…*), or a plural (*thanks are due to God…*).  In the sense of “expressions of gratitude”, it can be used as either of these, or also as a singular: *a special thanks is due to the chairman…*

[Sources for this: roughly counting hits for phrasings like *thanks is*, *thanks are* in Google and [COHA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).]

How did it get this way?  The entries for *thanks* in the OED tell a tangled tale, but as far as I can make out, *thank* was originally an acceptable singular noun (their last citation is 1642, *Is this the thanke which you returne to God?*), but the plural form *thanks* gradually predominated, and apparently lost its plural-ness to some extent.

This bit is confusing: the OED describes *thanks* here as “†Formerly sometimes construed as singular”, and their citations where it’s unambiguously singular stop after Shakespeare (1594, *Thanks to men Of Noble minds, is honourable meede.*), but all the later citations they give are completely ambiguous about its number (1805, *I return it to you with my sincere thanks.*), like most modern usage.  There are no citations where it’s unambiguously treated as plural.

Their earliest citation for the phrase *Many thanks* is 1803, *Many thanks for your letter.*  So this seems to arise some while after *thanks* was generally construed as plural!  I’d love to know more of the background here…

Answer (score 3):

It is heard several times every morning on BBC Radio 4's *Today* programme: it is the standard closing that they use after interviewing somebody.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your perspective. You can break it down far enough so that there's no way it's proper: What is a "thank?" Can such a thing be pluralized? Taken on its own, "many thanks" is a sentence fragment, and thus not truly proper.

In common use, though, I'd say it's a standard closing for a communication, like  "With kind regards, Joe Blow" and is entirely acceptable (though I admit that I don't care for using things like "many thanks" without also including the sender's name as a signature). It's vernacular, which is to say it's how the language is used, regardless of how proper it is grammatically speaking.

Answer (score 0):

I use it all the time.  I consider it shorthand for both "thank you very much" and "thank you in advance" and hence works at the end of almost any e-mail.

Comment: Related: [Can “thanks in advance” be considered rude?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/49218/161)

Comment: @NeilFein it can be a bit rude.  IMHO it works better when you already know the person is going to do what you've asked them to do, e.g. when you are following up on a request that you've already made verbally.  If you were cold-calling via e-mail, it could be considered a tad presumptuous.  In any case, there are far worse things you could do in e-mail: I give you the exclamation mark (!) as an example.  Consider "many thanks" vs. "many thanks!" and see if you can tell whether it is an exclamation or just sarcasm...