# Is thanks a countable noun? Many thanks or much thanks?

Tags: word-choice, differences, politeness, uncountable-nouns

A colleague of mine recently wrote in an email "much thanks for your efforts."   Does this usage make sense?  How does "much thanks" differ from "many thanks"?

This is similar to ["Is “Many thanks” a proper usage?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6541/is-many-thanks-a-proper-usage)

Comment: Much thanks - So many thanks that you can not count them any more ;-)

Comment: 'Thanks' is generally a non-count noun taking plural agreement. The expression 'many thanks' is a crystallised form, in which trying to decide whether 'thanks' is count or non-count is pointless ('many thanks' is idiomatic, but 'six thanks' is unacceptable).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Much thanks* means the same thing as *many thanks*, but *many thanks* is the standard form of this phrase, and *much thanks* is probably merely a corruption of the concept.  Basically, *thanks* is a plural noun (think of each "thank" as an individual expression of gratefulness).

[Grammar Girl](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/much-thanks-or-many-thanks.aspx) has a post relating to and pertinently addressing this topic:

> **..."Which is correct: *much thanks* or *many thanks*? I hear *much thanks* but it just doesn't sound right."**
>
> According to the [Merriam-Webster Online dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/thanks), "thanks" is plural, having come from the Middle English singular word "thank." Therefore, "many thanks" is the right phrase because we use "many" with plural count nouns, and we use "much" with mass nouns.

As to popularity, [Ngrams](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=much%20thanks,many%20thanks&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3), [Google searching](http://www.google.com/), [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/), and [BNC](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/) all concur in that *many thanks* is vastly more common.

Perusing [Google Books](http://books.google.com/) led me to a [charming passage](http://books.google.com/books?id=IwdSAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA69&dq=%22much%20thanks%22%20%22incomparable%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=4-1YT_7aCsj30gGF2pS_Dw&ved=0CEQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22much%20thanks%22%20%22incomparable%22&f=false) in a publication of letters to the editor which touches on this topic:

> **157.**--In your article on "[Incomparable Wessex, Again](http://books.google.com/books?id=_0QDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA410&lpg=PA410&dq=%22incomparable%20wessex%22%20%22much%20thanks%22&source=bl&ots=V7V-6wUulu&sig=YeGkM_VKrLnQYkKS6eG4EDoeGv8&hl=en&sa=X&ei=q-1YT5j4BMr50gGLi63NDw&ved=0CCIQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22incomparable%20wessex%22%20%22much%20thanks%22&f=false)," in the May number, I see the expression "Much thanks."  Will you kindly tell me if this is correct?  Should it not be "Many thanks"?
>
> Undoubtedly it should, though the writer may have had Shakespeare in mind.  See "Hamlet," Act I, Scene 1.  Still, the expression "Thank you!" or "I thank you!" is always to be preferred to "Many thanks!" or "Thanks!"

Comment: so is "much thanks" actually wrong?  Since much is used with uncountable nouns and thanks is not an uncountable noun.

Comment: Pedantically, it is, but are you going to tell Shakespeare?  You could also reason your way out by inferring that the idea of a *thank* is absurd, and *thanks*, like love, is a mass moun. Be that as it may, I will neither endorse it nor commit myself to its demise (since the lines are, as demonstrated, a little blurred).  Grammar isn't always hard and fast rules.

Comment: Language changes. Shakespeare uses all sorts of obsolete expressions. I suspect *thanks* was used as a mass noun much more then.

Answer (score 5):

In Act I, Scene i of ‘Hamlet’, Francisco says ‘For this relief much thanks.’ That may still be found in modern usage as your colleague has shown, but 'many thanks’ is much more usual. The Corpus of Contemporary English, for example, has 13 records of ‘much thanks’, against 243 of ‘many thanks’.

Comment: Yes, but I can't help thinking OP's colleague isn't a native speaker - or if she *is*, she's probably not what I would call a very competent one. As per your citation, *much thanks* would have been fine in Elizabethan times, but it sounds really weird to me in the context of emails.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Indeed.

Comment: I have nothing to indicate that my colleague is not a native speaker.  His name is very American and he speaks very natively, so it surprised me to see him use this form in an email.